# Tally data from 1 sheet conditionally to variable rows of another based on a value in source row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to solve an Excel issue: I have a table of data in 1 sheet, with several columns of values. One of those columns is an identifier value, calculated by a function applied to some of the other values in that row (ie. If a3/b3>5 but < 10, then the identifier value for row 3= 18, if a3/b3=10, then ID value =22, etc), each row has an ID that can = anything from 1-120. This number corresponds directly to a row in the target sheet, so target sheet has 120 rows with the same columns matching the data columns of the source

What I need to do is take the data from the source sheet and add it incrementally to the corresponding columns in the target sheet, so there is a running accumulating tally- but tally the data from the source rows into the target rows that have the same ID-  so for example, all source sheet rows that have ID value of 47 have their data tallied only into the various columns in row 47 of the target sheet, and so on- so all data in the source gets tallied, but only into one row of the target, determined by the source row’s ID value. The source sheet will grow over time with more rows of data,  resulting with ever increasing values in the target sheet that will always have exactly 120 rows.

I’m a not an experienced coder, good enough to google how to do what I need to do and figure it out usually, but this one is a little more complex than what I’ve done before

Edited to add example:
[image]

So in the example above, in the source sheet, an ID value of 12 appears for 4 of the visible rows. What I need is for that to result with the target sheet's row that has an ID value of 12, (target sheet row 17) to have it's columns show the aggregate total of values for the corresponding cells in all the source sheet's rows that have ID=12. So in this case, target sheet row 17 "Bonus" cell should = 0, "No Bonus" should = 4, "No Multiplier" should equal 2, "2x Multiplier" should = 1, etc.

This should apply for all data in the source doc, so each source row will have its values added to the tally of one specific target row, defined by a match of ID value

I saw the edit earlier adding the VBA tag, I'm unfamiliar with using that, but can probably figure it out if necessary with a little guidance :)

Comment: There's no way to do this with just excel-formula, so I have added the vba tag.  Those answering should keep in mind that the OP may also need to know how to add and apply the vba code.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question completely at first, but with the given data please try:
`=SUM(IF(SourceSheet!$B$2:$B$13=TargetSheet!$M6,IF(SourceSheet!$C$1:$H$1=TargetSheet!N$5,SourceSheet!$C$2:$H$13)))`
Paste this in Target sheet cell N6 with `ctrl + shift + enter` and drag down/right.
You need to change the Sheet names to the actual sheet names and the range to the actual range.

Comment: Is the ID already calculated in the source sheet, or does that need implemented also?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I edited the OP with an image example and further detailed explanation

Comment: I totally changed my answer with the given data. I misunderstood completely at first, but I think this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you!! It looks like this did the trick- pasting into N6 alone with ctrl+shift+enter didn't do it, but I realized I just needed to drag it down all the rows, then across all the columns.  Thanks for taking the time to figure this out

Comment: Yes, drag is necessary. Updated my answer  glad I could help. Another thing is that you need to make sure the headers are matches. Done headers currently are no exact match.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. One more question on this- in your formula, I'm currently defining the total rows in the source with a fixed number... I'd like to be able to have that row total be a variable equal to the total number of rows in the source, since as more data is added to source, the row numbers increase. I've found the following formula to work fine to get that number: =ROW(OFFSET(SourceResults!$A1,COUNTA(SourceResults!A:A)-1,0))... But I'm not sure how to replace the "463" in "$C$2:$C$463" with the formula above. If this possible?

Comment: I actually was able to figure this last part out, using INDIRECT